# Set a variable to a fix value in QML

Tags: qt, qml

In QML, I want to create a text moving when the mouse in on it. When the mouse is not on it anymore, it should go back to its original position. The value of the variable 'toogle' in the code is true when my mouse is on the text, false when its not.

```
property real distance: myText.x

...

Text {
     id: myText

     property bool toogle
     x:toogle?distance+2:distance        
    }
```

The problem is obviously that the value of distance will be increased when the mouse is on the text and that it will create a loop: the text will be always moving as long as the mouse is on it.

How can I save the value of the original x position of the text when it's created, and keep it unmodified to avoid having this undesired loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a property and set it to a fixed value whenever the component loading is completed:

```
// Keep track of the original position.
property real originalPosition;

Component.onCompleted: {
    originalPosition = myText.x;
}
```

I am a bit confused with your question though, do you want the text to keep moving or not whenever the mouse hovers over the text? The code you posted already contains a binding loop.

To detect mouse hovers you can define a MouseArea within your Text element and listen to the 'containsMouse' property to be able to reset the text's position:

```
MouseArea {
    id: mouseArea
    width: parent.width
    height: parent.height
    hoverEnabled: true
    onContainsMouseChanged: {
        console.log("Changed: " + containsMouse);
        if (!containsMouse) {
            myText.x = myText.originalPosition;
        } else {
            myText.x = mouseArea.containsMouse ? myText.originalPosition+2: myText.originalPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

This last implementation will only move the text 2 pixels whenever the text is hovered and back to the original position whenever the mouse stops hovering. It will NOT continuously move the text 2 pixels when hovered.